# Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Uri'. Cannot convert the "@{

Tags: arrays, powershell, for-loop, foreach

Would like to retrive innerText of a P html element for all the URLS i got listed in a text file. I'm rather newbie for this, but thought i can solve it. Atm. i've failed, as i can't handle how i shall pass each array items for the loop correctly:

```
$theURLS = Import-CSV linkek_alatt.txt
$item = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
for ($i=0; $i -le $theURLS.length;$i++)
{
foreach($item in $theURLS)
{
$Site = Invoke-WebRequest -URI $item
$Igotit = $Site.AllElements | Where-Object {$_.tagName -eq "P"} |
Select -First 1 -Skip 3 -ExpandProperty innerText
$Igotit
}
}
> FilteredContent.txt
```

The Filtered file shall contain the informations.

For now, i receive a "Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Uri'. Cannot convert the "@{" error and i see repeated first URL and a random - the one for next step - one in the error message. Any ideas welcome.
Best regards,
Geza

Comment: Text file or csv file? If text file, don't use `Import-Csv`, use `Get-Content`

Comment: Why are you iterating through your URL list inside of an iteration through your URL list?

Comment: CSV. Atm. i'm working on it a bit more. This works for one specified URL: Clear-Host
$Site = Invoke-WebRequest -URI "https://www.somepage/anotherone/"
$Igotit = $Site.AllElements | Where-Object {$_.tagName -eq "P"} |
Select -First 1 -Skip 3 -ExpandProperty innerText
$Igotit

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments, the issue occurs because you are using `Import-CSV` here:

```
$theURLS = Import-CSV linkek_alatt.txt
```

This attempts to create a PowerShell object by using the first line of text in the file as headers.

If your .txt file is not a .csv file and you want to return an array of strings, instead use `Get-Content`:

```
$theURLS = Get-Content linkek_alatt.txt
```

If your file is a CSV file, then you'll need to reference the property name that matches the header of the URLs when using it in `Invoke-WebRequest`. E.g if it had a header of "URL":

```
Invoke-WebRequest -URI $item.URL
```

But I suspect this is not the case for you.

Comment: Thanks Mark, i missed the header and that .URL extension as well. As i said, i'm rather newbie :). It is a CSV file, the urls are separated by the ; sign.